# how to load data using keras/PyTorch which has multiple nested directories

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I have nested directories Like this

```
MainData/
    Real/
        /c1
        /c2
        /c3
        /c4
    Fake/
        /c1
        /c2
        /c3
        /c4
```

I want to train my CNN which first predicts if the image is real/fake then only it predicts its class as the Fake data is generated by Gan, it does look like real data.
The problem is I am trying this method

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=img_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=['Real', 'Fake', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
)
```

However, it only loads data in Real /Fake classes, not in others

Can Someone please guide me on how to perform the prediction? I want 2 labels but from different ranges of classes and I am not even able to load the dataset.
P.S: All the sub-directories in Fake/Real data are named the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your dataset & classes to look like this :

```
MainData/
    Real_c1
    Real_c2
    Real_c3
    Real_c4
    Fake_c1
    Fake_c2
    Fake_c3
    Fake_c4
```

Then change your datagen to :

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=img_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=['Real_c1', ..., 'Fake_c4']
)
```